# How to get time-consuming information of a block in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I'm trying to build a blockChain explorer backend through Fabric JAVA SDK. How can I get a time-consuming information of a block?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read about how to ask good questions, as well as this question checklist. Lastly please learn how to create a minimal reproducible example to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, it ought to be through the operations service: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/operations_service.html

There is already interesting work done with Prometheus and Grafana:

- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/metrics_reference.html#prometheus-metrics
- https://medium.com/@ongkhaiwei/monitoring-hyperledger-fabric-components-using-prometheus-92e8bea1f51b

Other than this, the other information you can get from a block in your client is  through `registerBlockEvent`, but I think it does not fit your requirements: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/EventHub.html#registerBlockEvent

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've noticed a metric named 'ledger_block_processing_time', and I've checked it and found that it only offers me the informations like 'how many block's been processed in seconds'. I wondered if I can get the informations that tells me how long dose a specific block consume time?